# How to let list can convert to my class object implicitly?

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

For example, I have a class `Point` and has a function

```
void foo(Point pt);
```

call it as

```
foo({1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: add a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list<int>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cassert>

struct bar
{
    void foo(const std::initializer_list<int>& bits)
    {
        assert(bits.size() == 3);
        auto i = bits.begin();
        x = *i++;
        y = *i++;
        z = *i++;
    }

    int x, y, z;
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
    b.foo({0, 1, 2});
}
```

Comment: `initializer_list` is designed to be cheaply passed by value.

Answer (score -2):

You have to have constructor which takes three ints. Consider:

```
struct Point {
    Point (int p1_, int p2_, int p3_) : p1 {p1_}, p2 {p2_}, p3 {p3_} {}

    int p1;
    int p2;
    int p3;
};

void foo (Point pt) {
    std::cout << pt.p1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << pt.p2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << pt.p3 << std::endl;
}
```

and usage:

```
foo ({1, 2, 3});
std::cout << std::endl;
foo ({4, 5, 6});
```